# How can i change the color of each circle. I mean the one circle color different from another

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

How can i change the color of each circle i as you can see in image

```
for i,x in locations.iteritems():
    ax.add_patch(Circle(xy=[i[2], i[1]], radius=get_radius(x), color=['red','blue','green'], alpha=0.6, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()))
plt.show()
```

```
ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: ['red', 'blue', 'green']
```

Comment: The error's pretty clear? `color=...` wants [a valid color](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colors.html), and a list with three strings in it is not a valid color.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to use a list of 3 values ranged from 0 to 255. Like this:

```
for i,x in locations.iteritems():
ax.add_patch(Circle(xy=[i[2], i[1]], radius=get_radius(x), color=[255, 255, 255], alpha=0.6, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())) # Change these to the color values you want. Keep in mind that 255 is the max, and it will throw an error otherwise.
plt.show()
```

If red blue and green are variables, then you need to remove the quotes like this:

```
for i,x in locations.iteritems():
ax.add_patch(Circle(xy=[i[2], i[1]], radius=get_radius(x), color=[red,blue,green], alpha=0.6, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()))
plt.show()
```

Hope this helped! Best of luck!